# Find style.css using CSS class in a website

Tags: php, html, css, dokan

I'm using Dokan plugin for my website. My problem is need to remove extra space between heading & banner (Check [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqQlc.png)). And I find a solution using web inspect tool. If i change the padding-bottom to 0px its working fine.(check [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4tHr.png)). so I try to find that CSS class in my website backend, i found a same CSS class regarding my issue but if I change it not working in my website.

The CSS class in martfury/style.css

```
.page-header-page .entry-title {
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

I search every CSS file but nothing found also try to clear data. Nothing help me. If any one know how to solve this please help me.

I'm really thankful for your time.

Comment: try with !important like =  `padding-bottom:0px !important;`

Comment: sir, thank you soo much. Its working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with `!important` like given below

```
padding-bottom:0px !important;
```

I think you CSS not able to overwrite so `!important` will be work there.